# Order conversations in twilio conversations

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-conversations

I need to receive conversations in order of last message, or at least date updates.

In twilio conversation [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations) there is a [method](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-conversation-resource) to get user's conversations. But there is not a word about ordering, only the limit

My code:

```
const conversations = await client.conversations.v1
      .users(user.twilioId)
      .userConversations.list({ limit: 20 });
```

Comment: Is the response that you get not already sorted?

Comment: @IObert It sorted but as I understood by create date

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, you need to fetch all and sort them manually.

Comment: Yes, I found one solution where I can duplicate conversations in my database and using webhooks, when a user sends a message, update them. But now I can't find how to get the conversation sid in the webhook